# Filter dropdown bar does stays collapsed even after navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am designing a website which has a Filter Dropdown Bar that filters blog posts via Categories. The issue I am facing right now is that once I click the Filter Bar, the drop-down collapses which is correct. But when I select a Category from the Filter Bar, it navigates to that Category page but the Filter Bar stays collapsed. I want it to close after navigating to another category page.

Here is the jQuery I am using -

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".blog-filter").insertAfter(".header-row-2");
        if ($('.bold-filter-icon').length > 0) {
        $('.blog-filter').show();
        $('.blog-filter-btn').attr('data-toggled', 'on');
        $('.bold-filter-icon').attr('href',
        '/@SiteMap.CurrentNode.Url.Split(' / ').Last()');
        $(".blog-filter-btn span").removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');}
       $('.header-row-2').on('click', '.blog-filter-btn', function()
       {
       if (!$(this).attr('data-toggled') || $(this).attr('data-toggled') ==='off')
           {
            $(this).attr('data-toggled', 'on');
            $(this).find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
            $('.blog-filter').show();
           }

        else if ($(this).attr('data-toggled') === 'on' || $('.blog-filter').is(':visible')) 
           {
           $(this).attr('data-toggled', 'off');
           $(this).find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
           $('.blog-filter').hide();
        }  
     });
  });
```